# Jenkins pipeline - File not found exception

Tags: json, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am getting file not exception in jenkins although the file is available in the expected location.
What i am trying to do here is, getting the latest committed file and storing in filescommitted variable later passing that as input to readJSON file. Seems the variable value is passed but unable to find the file in the location.

Error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /appl/JenkinsSlave/workspace/SDA_WIP_development/RA agent/java-infra-war-tomcat-piaas.json
 does not exist.
```

It works only if i hardcode the file name

```
readJSON file: "java-infra-war-tomcat-piaas.json"
```

It does not work for the below cases. Can anyone tel me what is the issue please ?

```
readJSON file: filesCommitted
readJSON file: "${env.WORKSPACE}/${filesCommitted}"
readJSON file: "${WORKSPACE}/${filesCommitted}"
```

Jenkins pipeline script:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
        import groovy.json.*
        import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

        node('java'){
            def gitURL = Git_URL as String
            def branchName = Branch as String
            def GitHubCredentialsId = GitHub_Credentials_Id as String
            def filesCommitted

            stage('Clean')
            {
              deleteDir()   
            }

            stage('SCM')
            {
                git branch: branchName, credentialsId: GitHubCredentialsId, url: gitURL
                filesCommitted = sh(script:'git diff --name-only HEAD^', returnStdout:true)
                def files = sh(script: "find . -name '*.json'", returnStdout:true)    
                println ("new files commited:" + filesCommitted)
                println ("all files commited:" + files)
                sh "pwd"
                sh "ls"
            }

            stage('Add agents in RA'){
                //def infra_file = unstashParam "infrafile"
                //println(infra_file)
                println(env.WORKSPACE)
                println (filesCommitted)
                def projects = readJSON file: "${env.WORKSPACE}/${filesCommitted}"
                println(projects)
             }
}
```

Complete jenkins console output:

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ git diff --name-only 'HEAD^'
[Pipeline] sh
+ find . -name '*.json'
[Pipeline] echo
new files commited:java-infra-war-tomcat-piaas.json

[Pipeline] echo
all files commited:./java-infra-ear-jboss-piaas.json
./java-infra-war-tomcat-piaas.json
./java-infra-war-tomcat-piaas_demo.json
./angular-infra-zip-iis-piaas.json
./dotnet-infra-zip-iis-piaas.json

[Pipeline] sh
+ pwd
/appl/JenkinsSlave/workspace/SDA_WIP_development/RA agent
[Pipeline] sh
+ ls
angular-infra-zip-iis-piaas.json
dotnet-infra-zip-iis-piaas.json
java-infra-ear-jboss-piaas.json
java-infra-war-tomcat-piaas_demo.json
java-infra-war-tomcat-piaas.json
README.md
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Add agents in RA)
[Pipeline] echo
java-infra-war-tomcat-piaas.json

[Pipeline] readJSON
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /appl/JenkinsSlave/workspace/SDA_WIP_development/RA agent/java-infra-war-tomcat-piaas.json
 does not exist.
```

Comment: `readJSON` path is relative to WORKSPACE, so you should not prepend WORKSPACE to the path. I think you need to split `filesCommitted` on newline, loop over the result and pass each path to `readJSON`. Currently you are trying to pass potentially multiple paths to a single call of `readJSON`, but the function expects a single path.

Comment: @zett42 But the 'filecommitted' variable has only one file name value which is basically the latest file committed. 'file' variable has multiple file names. I am not able to understand

Comment: Ok I might have misunderstood the code. It looks like there is an extraneous linebreak at the end of `filesCommitted` though. This could work: `readJSON file: filesCommitted.trim()`

Comment: @zett42 Thank you , Indeed you right and i didnt think in that way..readJSON file: filesCommitted.trim() works. This really cost me a day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is an extraneous linebreak at the end of `filesCommitted` content.

Try this:

```
filesCommitted = sh(script:'git diff --name-only HEAD^', returnStdout:true).trim()

def projects = readJSON file: filesCommitted
```

It is usually a good habit to add a `trim()` to the `sh` step when using `returnStdout:true`. This will remove any extraneous whitespace before and after the returned string.